# How to get macos app signing set up for packages

Tags: macos, go, code-signing

I am new to macOS development and am having a terrible time trying to get my code signed. The documentation to me seems to be horrible.

My specific situation...

- I am building a cross-platform app that runs on Linux, Windows, macOS and eventually iOS and Android.
- It is a console app that runs as a service or LaunchDaemon
- It has a UI served by WebView, http, or console commands depending on the scenario.
- It is built with Go 17 in VScode.
- I am not using xCode other than the command line tools.
- My goal on macOS it to distribute it as a package (pkg) and not as an app.
- I have been using MunkiPkg to build it

I am hung up on understanding how the various certificates need to be set up. I have not been able to get a successfully signed package notarized.

Can someone please point me to some documentation that explains how my scenario works? Most of what I found requires it to be built in xCode. And the Apple docs seem mostly to focus on how great their tools are without actually explaining how to use them.

Help!